# JQuery : How to handle event of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

On my view page I use Ajax and JQuery to get the data from Codeigniter's controller and then return it to view page in html format.

Here is the code of the Ajax post

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var fileId = 0;
        var wrapper = $("#preference");
        var add_button = $("#btn_Add");
        var x = 0;

     $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>'+'index.php/client/ajax_cat',{}, function(returned){
            $('#preference').append(returned);
        });
     });

     $(wrapper).on("click","#btnRemove", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".tr").remove(); 
        x--;

     });

      $('.selCat').change(function(){
        alert('changed');

      });
```

And here is the code inside the controller :

```
public function ajax_cat(){

        $result = $this->preference->getSubCategory2();

        $subcats = array();

        $subcats['0'] = '-Select a category-';

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            # code...
            $key = $row->cat2code;
            $value = $row->cat2name_EN;
            //echo $key;
            $subcats[$key] = $value;
        }

        $form_dropdown = form_dropdown('selCat', $subcats,'0', 'class="selCat"');

        $output = '<div class="tr">' 
            .   '<div class="td">Category :</div>'
            .   '<div class="td">'
            .   $form_dropdown
            .   '</div>'
            .   '<div class="td">Sub Category :</div>'
            .   '<div class="td">'
            .       '<select class="selSubCat">'
            .           '<option value="0" selected="true">-Select a category first-</option>'
            .       '</select>'
            .   '</div>'
            .   '<div class="td">Score :</div>'
            .   '<div class="td"><input type="text" size="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="btnRemove">Remove&nbsp;[-]</a></div>'
            .   '</div>';

            echo $output;

    }
```

What I would like to do is when the dropdown "selCat" is changed, I will do another Ajax post to get the data corresponding to the previous selection of that particular dropdown.

How can I handle the event change of particular dropdown since my dropdown is dynamic ?

I tried to do with

```
$('.selCat').change(function(){
        alert('changed');

      });
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple IDs with the same name - that's invalid.

Comment: Should I add the number to each id, like category_1, category_2 and etc ? Or is it better to attach javascript function in each dropdown element to track the change ?

Comment: Can you use a class?

Comment: I have added class attribute to my form_dropdown in the controller function and used it in the jquery function but it still does not work. I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in DOM loading and initialisation.

Try adding the `change()` bit directly after the appending:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var fileId = 0;
        var wrapper = $("#preference");
        var add_button = $("#btn_Add");
        var x = 0;

     $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>'+'index.php/client/ajax_cat',{}, function(returned){
            $('#preference').append(returned);

            //NEW BIT!
            $('.selCat').change(function(){
               alert('changed');
            });
            //end new bit
        });
     });

     $(wrapper).on("click","#btnRemove", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".tr").remove(); 
        x--;

     });
```

Comment: No probs, you could experiment with using `.on('change')` instead of `.change()` but there is definitely an inconsistency in jQuery somewhere or something... I think...

Comment: That is not an inconsistency – the selector used simply just looks for elements that are part of the DOM at the time it is executed, and therefor any elements that are added only later on are not “caught”. A solution to this is to use event delegation, in the same way as is already happening here with `$(wrapper).on("click","#btnRemove", function(e){ …`

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the clarification!